# Is it possible to create an .exe executable file using Java?

Tags: java, deployment, installation, executable

I am not talking about the *executable jar file*, instead the **.exe** file for windows can that be generated for Java apps. I know there is some projects like JSmooth etc., so I am a little curious to know how they create exe's for jar or class files.

Comment: honestly, you need to rephrase the question in the title

Comment: If the app. has a GUI, a better option is to install it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a .bat file (windows script) that launches the executable jars? The effect will be the same: user double-clicks and launches the app.

Comment: True . But what i expect is to create an real exe is that possibel